# Bash block and return codes --- need explanation

Tags: bash

I've been using Bash for a long time, but it seems I still miss something. Please consider this code:

```bsh
function surprise {
    true && {
        echo 'Expected';
        false;
    } || {
        echo 'Unexpected';
    }
}

surprise;
```

which is shortened demonstration of my real problem and the output:

```
Expected
Unexpected
```

Till now I have thought, that whatever "Expected" block returns does not affect `||` in front of the "Unexpected" block, but it seems, like `||` is not checked against the output of `true` command, but in fact of the `false` command inside brackets.

Can someone, please, explain, what actually just happened? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems, like || is not checked against the output of true command, but in fact of the false command inside brackets.

You could say that's the case.

`x && y || z` **is not** an if/then/else structure, nor should be used as one. It is a combination of boolean operators – the equivalent of "x AND y OR z" – and will evaluate as many commands as it needs to in order to determine the result. (The evaluation is left-to-right unless grouped by parentheses or braces, just like in most programming languages, so the order is `(x && y) || z`.)

So in order to determine the result of `x && y`, when *x* is true, *y* must also be evaluated. On the other hand, when *x* is false, the result will be false no matter what, so it'll just short-circuit and skip the evaluation of *y*.

Whether the values in between are single commands or `{cmd; cmd; cmd}` blocks actually doesn't matter at all; in this situation it merely helps you see the actual effects.

Comment: The short-circuit... I really thought of `&&` and `||` more like `if-then-else`, but now I get it--thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First: you can think of each of the "blocks" as just complex commands, not something significantly different. Thus, what you really have is just:

```
cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3
```

...and the fact that `cmd2` and `cmd3` are blocks rather than simple commands doesn't matter. Now, the important thing is that given that command sequence, the logical precedence of `&&` and `||` "operators" makes it something like this:

```
( cmd1 && cmd2 ) || cmd3
```

(Note: actually, those parentheses would force a subshell. I'm ignoring that.) If you look at the logical structure of that, it's `( something ) || cmd3`, so clearly it's going to run `cmd3` if `something` fails. But `something` is actually `cmd1 && cmd2`, which succeeds if *both `cmd1` and `cmd2` succeed -- which means it fails if *either* `cmd1` or `cmd2` fails.

So, logically, that'll wind up running `cmd3` if *either* `cmd1` or `cmd2` fails. In your actual code, `cmd2` always fails, so `cmd3` always runs.

Answer (score 0):

The double and (`&&`) and the double pipe (`||`) have meaning in process control in Linux.

Think of them as logical operators.

```
command1 && command2
```

or

```
command1 || command2
```

Or

```
command1 && command2 || command3
```

Basically, in all 3 cases, `command1` runs.  If it has a NON-ZERO exit status (an error of some type) it is considered to not have successfully run.

With the `&&` - thinking of a logical AND in programming - there is no need to run the second command, because the first one failed in some way.

With the `||` - thinking of a logical OR - the if the first is successful (exit 0) there is no need to check the second condition - only one or the other has to be successful.

With the 3rd example, if `command1` is successful, it will run `command2`.  If it wasn't successful, it will instead run `command3`

In your example, the `||` is detecting the exit status of your `false` command.